# Constructor not accepting parameter being passed through it

Tags: java, types, constructor, abstract

```
public abstract class shape {
    protected double volume;
    protected double surface;
}

public class cube extends shape {
    public double side;
    public double newSide;

    public cube(double side) {
        side = newSide;
    }

    public void volume(double newSide){
        System.out.println (newSide);
    }
}

public class shapes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        cube a = new cube(5);
        a.volume();
    }
}
```

This outputs the error:

```
constructor cube in class cube cannot be applied to given types;
cube a = new cube(5.5);
required: double
found:    no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I have all the variable set to double, so not sure why it is complaining.

Comment: You are assigning `newSide` to `side` which essentially does nothing given your parameter is `side`. I believe you mean to do `this.side = side` in your constructor

Comment: If I do public cube(double side) { this.side=side;} I receive the same error.

Comment: It is not the constructor call that is giving the error, it is the `volume()` call.

Comment: Please also post your purpose of the code. So that others can understand and provide solution.

Answer (score 2):

First, your constructor is wrong. It should be

```
public cube(double side) {
        this.side = side;
    }
```

And you are getting the error because you set an argument for volume as such -

```
 public void volume(double newSide){
        System.out.println (newSide);
    }
```

change it to

```
public void volume(){
    System.out.println(side);
}
```

In java, you should always capitalize class names. it should be Cube.

Comment: I tried this, and it produced exactly the same error.

Comment: ?? it's working for me: https://onecompiler.com/java/3wve2kxsu

Comment: That is so weird. I actually copied and pasted what you did there and it putout the same error.

Comment: Ok I replace my main class with yours. As in I deleted the file and created a new one and it worked! I see that in mine I have the Main class under the shapes class, would this be why it didn't work?

Comment: The class you have main method inside must match the name of the file.Which is also why it's necessary to use capital letter for class names. In your case, it would've been Shape.java since your main method is under Shape class.

Answer (score 1):

1. As you have not done anything by inheriting the Shape class, I ignored the class.
2. As [JordanKobeWade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11598180/jordankobewade) said, you wrongly did an assignment inside the constructor and also you declared the volume method with a parameter but you called it without a parameter. Then you got an error.
3. If your intention is just to pass a value to another class and to print it, then the below code is fine.

Cube.java

```
public class Cube {

public double side;

public Cube(double side) {
    this.side = side;
}

public void volume(){
    System.out.println (side);
}

}
```

And Shapes.java

```
public class Shapes {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cube a = new Cube(5);
    a.volume();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean that I have done nothing by inheriting the Shapes class. It is an Abstract class. My understanding as that it doesn't do anything but declare undefined methods and variables to be extended to child classes. Is that not correct, and what I have done?

Comment: You are correct. But, What I am trying to say you should declare some abstract methods which can be implemented by sub-class methods. So that you are completing its purpose. As I have you not used the variables in the subclass, which were declared in the super-class.